# Tensor shape no callable using Lambda function in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-lambda

Hi I'm new using tensorflow backend and I'm getting this error using a Lambda function in tensorflow.keras

```
TypeError: <tf.Tensor 'Reshape_5:0' shape=(1, 63, 63, 1) dtype=float32> is not a callable object
```

The function I'm using in Lambda is:

```
def GD(u):
  u=k.reshape(u,shape=(3969,1))
  u1=[]
  for j in range(3969):
    u1.append(k.sum(u))
  u1=tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(u1, dtype=tensorflow.float32)
  u1=u1/k.max(u1)
  u1=tensorflow.reshape(u1,shape=(-1,63,63,1))
  return u1
```

I call the function to the network as:

```
Inputs1=Input(shape=(63,63,1))
x=Lambda(grad1(Inputs1))
```

Comment: What is `grad1`, and where are you using `GD`?

Comment: it doesn't seem like you are calling the function anywhere, or perhaps there is something we are missing